# How to resize freely the embedded google map size on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to resize freely the height of a embedded google map on wordpress ?
Here is my site : http://hernehillintersport.co.uk/ (map is on the footer)
And here is my code:

```
<div class="google-maps" style="width:100%;
height:10%">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2486.269500512604!2d-0.10340518384300397!3d51.45320817962627!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4876047316c9ef45%3A0xe3c85773f0550ed7!2sIntersport!5e0!3m2!1ses!2suk!4v1444382506674" width="400" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I already tried to modify into the < div > tag or directly with the width/height into the code. However I can't decrease the height's size anymore to a certain extent. I suppose, it's the same for the wight.
That's why I would like to know how can I resize the map freely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to answer this in comment but i think you defined the width and height in your code which is the reason you cant decrease it. Just don't define height or set is auto it should work.